# Accessing files in sub directory of main program

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The folder containing my main executable is very cluttered with input, output and source files. I would like to move some of these files into a different directory to my executable but still be able to access them. It would be fantastic if I could make a directory, for example `./main/outfile`, that holds all the output files from my program. Is it possible to include a path when accessing these files in Fortran 77/90?

If compilers are of any importance, I use gfortran which is running on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for input/output files, just specify the path when you are opening the file. For example:

```
open(unit=3,file='outputdata/data_modified.txt',status='unknown')
```

will open a file in the `outputdata` folder. Note that the `outputdata` folder has to exist beforehand, or you will likely get an error.

Comment: You should emphasise that the directory `outputdata` should exist before this command is called. At least with ifort, if I try to write a file in a directory that does not exist I get a "file not found" error.

Comment: What about for include statements at the end of MAIN? I do not think 'include' accepts a path input. I have a very long list of include statements which means I have a lot of included files cluttering up the same directory that my MAIN is in. Should I just copy and paste all of these subroutines into a single .f file to include at the end of the program?

Comment: @kxk7607 No, don't do that. The same path method will work for include files as well. You can put an include file in the folder `includefiles` and specify it in your main program with `include includefiles/statements.inc`.

Comment: @bananafish I am not familiar with an include file (`.inc` extension). Does this organize all of the desired files into a single statement? It would be great if I could point to a directory and include all of the files with in. Is that what the `.inc` file does?

Comment: @kxk7607 no, `.inc` is just an arbitrary extension, it can be any file which contains fortran code valid at the point in your program you're calling it. are you including different functions/subroutines this way? if so, i'd look into putting a bunch of them into the same module (in the same file). and `use` the module in the main program.

Answer (score 2):

The starting directory at runtime is not the directory where your main program happens to reside, but rather the current directory when starting the program.

For instance

```
mkdir run_N && cd run_N && ../my_program
```

Will read and write files in the current directory (./run_N) even though the application binary is in another directory.

Comment: I was under the impression that MAIN generates an a.out (or some other specified output executeable) which is created in the same directory as MAIN. Am I to understand that moving a.out to, say the desktop, will not permit the program to execute properly? Forgive me, I am still in my FORTRAN infancy.