# Writing output files in different directory when many output files are being created

Tags: fortran, output

I am using fortran 95. I have a question very similar to [Accessing files in sub directory of main program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573475/accessing-files-in-sub-directory-of-main-program)

The additional problem that I am having is this: I am creating files in a loop using following commands:

```
write(fn,fmt='(a,i0,a)')"degseqA",filenumber,'.dat'
open(unit=filenumber,file=fn)
```

Hence I cannot use 'output/myfile.dat' to make myfile.dat go to the directory output. Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does somebody have any idea about achieving the same thing in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the directory already exists, it is totally straightforward.

```
write(fn,fmt='(a,i0,a)') "output/degseqA",filenumber,'.dat'

open(unit=filenumber,file=fn)
```

or in general

```
write(fn,fmt='(a,i0,a)') trim(directory_name)//"degseqA",filenumber,'.dat'
```

where `directory_name` is a character variable with the name of the directory.

Make sure `fn` is large enough.

Comment: Thank you very much Vladimir. This has solved my problem. :-)

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar - if it has, please feel free to accept the answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.